# How is WooCommerce cart.php template supposed to be used?

Tags: templates, plugins

I have a fresh install of Wordpress 3.5 and WooCommerce 1.6.6 (WC from now on) and use the default Twenty Twelve theme.

I added a Product to WC and when viewing that product and using the [Debug Bar Template Trace plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar-template-trace/) I can see that the template `woocommerce/templates/single-product.php` is used. However, if I view the Cart page, which was automatically generated by WooCommerce, it uses the `twentytwelve/page.php` template and not the `woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php` template, which I found surprising.

I'm a little confused from this outcome. Isn't the `cart.php` template supposed to be used for the Cart page? If not, what is that template for, and under which circumstances does it get used by WC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing the markup generated by `page.php` when the cart is displayed, it seems that the content is generated by `cart.php`, similarly to [loading a template part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part), so `cart.php` is actually used whenever the cart is displayed.

Comment: Correct in one.